# EMR and Pig running two steps, will common files from S3 be cached for reuse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig, emr

I want to run an EMR Pig job which at the moment is logically separated in to two scripts (and therefore two steps), however some of the data files are common between these two scripts, my question is will Pig recognize this when running the second step (second script) and reuse the files read from S3 or will it clear everything and do it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

If your EMR cluster is reading input data from S3, it doesn't copy the data to HDFS at all.

> Amazon EMR does not copy the data to local disk; instead the mappers
>   open multithreaded HTTP connections to Amazon S3, pull the data, and
>   process them in streams

However, it is not "caching" these streams for multiple passes:

> For iterative data processing jobs where data needs processing
>   multiple times with multiple passes, this is not an efficient
>   architecture. That’s because the data is pulled from Amazon S3 over
>   the network multiple times.

For this scenario, it is probably better to copy the common data to HDFS first with *S3DistCp*. If some of the artifacts you produce in your first step are useful in the second step, you could write those to HDFS for the second step to pick up in either case.

Reference: [AWS EMR Best Practices Guide](https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Amazon_EMR_Best_Practices.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use s3distcp to download files in HDFA on EMR. use files from HDFS for both pig scripts. So that files won't get downloaded each time.